# My Program don't work on any android device

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, publishing

I published an App to the Market but it is not available on HTC Desire and Motorola Milestone ...
This is the part from the Manifest that i understand filters the devices:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESSNETWORKSTATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITEEXTERNALSTORAGE" />
```

Does anybody have a hint for me?

Comment: Depending on where you are, the Milestone may be still on Eclair. But, that's API level 7 (or should be). Are you seeing this on many Milestones or just the one you're testing? Some regions/carriers got Froyo and others did not and it could be that the one you are testing is on 2.0.1 (API level 6). Further confounding the situation is that there is more than one phone called "Milestone" (A853 and XT720) in different regions.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are ok - but why don't you support small screens?

Desire is a 3.7 - which is on the larger end of the small screen range: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://www.htc.com/uk/product/desire/specification.html